EF Core code first column length change gets reverted
My app runs on .NET 7 with EF Core 7.0.5. I have two tables
SystemRole:
SystemRoleId PK nvarchar(50)

SystemAssociation (has clustered PK)
SystemId PK nvarchar(50) FK to SystemRole |
SystemRoleId PK nvarchar(50) FK to SystemRole |
SystemUserId PK nvarchar(50)

Both tables have data. I want to update the length of SystemRoleId in both tables. I added a new migration with
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(150)",
            maxLength: 150,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            type: "nvarchar(150)",
            maxLength: 150,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            columns: new[] { "SystemId", "SystemRoleId" },
            principalTable: "SystemRoles",
            principalColumns: new[] { "SystemId", "SystemRoleId" },
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150)",
            oldMaxLength: 150);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150)",
            oldMaxLength: 150);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            columns: new[] { "SystemId", "SystemRoleId" },
            principalTable: "SystemRoles",
            principalColumns: new[] { "SystemId", "SystemRoleId" },
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
    }

On migrate, the app errors on ALTER TABLE with constraint FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId. I tried a alternative with direct SQL in migration, that worked.
migrationBuilder.Sql("\r\nALTER TABLE [dbo].[SystemAssociations] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId]\r\n\r\nALTER TABLE SystemAssociations\r\nALTER COLUMN SystemRoleId NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL\r\n\r\nALTER TABLE SystemRoles\r\nALTER COLUMN SystemRoleId NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL\r\n\r\nALTER TABLE [dbo].[SystemAssociations]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId] FOREIGN KEY([SystemId], [SystemRoleId])\r\nREFERENCES [dbo].[SystemRoles] ([SystemId], [SystemRoleId])\r\n\r\nALTER TABLE [dbo].[SystemAssociations] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SystemAssociations_SystemRoles_SystemId_SystemRoleId]");

Not sure why SQL worked, but not the other.
Main problem is when I make new change to schema to migrate, I see a revert of column length added to the new migration. Example I added a new column I get this migration:
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150)",
            oldMaxLength: 150);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            type: "nvarchar(50)",
            maxLength: 50,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150)",
            oldMaxLength: 150);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Reason",
            table: "NotificationManagement",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Reason",
            table: "NotificationManagement");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(150)",
            maxLength: 150,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "SystemRoleId",
            table: "SystemAssociations",
            type: "nvarchar(150)",
            maxLength: 150,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(50)",
            oldMaxLength: 50);
    }

If I try to run this migration, it fails due to the FK.
Is there a way to avoid this revert on new migrations?
